# F# value restriction problem in reversing list

Tags: f#

The following F# code doesn't compile due to value restriction problem:

```
let x = List.rev []
```

But this compiles:

```
let x = List.rev [] in 3::x
```

As I understand it, the compiler infers that `x` must be of type `int list` so it doesn't compile.

The following doesn't compile:

```
let x = List.rev [] in (3::x, true::x)
```

But this does:

```
let x = ([]) in (3::x, true::x)
```

Why?

Comment: You can read about value restriction in different articles, e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mulambda/finer-points-of-f-value-restriction) or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/automatic-generalization)

Comment: Type inference can travel in any direciton. For `List.rev : 'a list -> 'a list`, there is no type of `'a` that can satisfy both `int` and `bool`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand it*, there are two ways to declare a value in F#:

- Value has a concrete type (e.g. `List<int>`). You must either explicitly specify this concrete type, or the compiler must be able to infer it.
- Value has a generic type (e.g. `List<'t>`). You must either explicitly specify this generic type, or the compiler must be able to infer it **and the value must be a simple immutable value**.

With that in mind, here are the explanations for what you're seeing:

```
// not allowed because x is generic, but not simple
let x = List.rev []

// allowed because the compiler can infer x's concrete type (List<int>)
let x = List.rev [] in 3::x

// not allowed because x is generic, but not simple
let x = List.rev [] in (3::x, true::x)

// allowed because x is both generic and simple (compiler can tell it's the empty list)
let x = ([]) in (3::x, true::x)
```

* The value restriction can be tricky, so there may be nuances I've overlooked in my explanation.